# Best way to share function with setState in ReactJS?

Tags: reactjs, axios

What is the best way to share function if the function inside involves setState?
I have a user auth function that share across all pages.

I have a routing page as follows:

```
function App() {
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <Switch>
        <Route exact path="/">
          <Login/>
        </Route>
        <Route path="/pageA">
          <Navbar/>
          <Page content={PageA}/>
        </Route>
        <Route path="/pageB">
          <Navbar/>
          <Page content={PageB}/>
        </Route>
...
```

Let say PageA and PageB have this function inside

```
    const axiosJWT = axios.create();

    axiosJWT.interceptors.request.use(async (config) => {
        const currentDate = new Date();
        if (expire * 1000 < currentDate.getTime()) {
            const response = await axios.get(`http://${host}/token`);
            config.headers.Authorization = `Bearer ${response.data.accessToken}`;
            setToken(response.data.accessToken);
            const decoded = jwt_decode(response.data.accessToken);
            setName(decoded.username);
            setExpire(decoded.exp);
        }
        return config;
    }, (error) => {
        return Promise.reject(error);
    });
```

As you see I have setState that needs to be done. If I have to setup a Util.js for the share function is the only way of doing it is by using input params and returns?
Do I make const axiosJWT on every page or in the Util.js?

Answer (score 0):

If you need to use a function more than once while coding, it's recommended to extract it as a public function and save it in util.js.